# Student distribution for correlation of Gaussian samples

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, correlation

Given indpendent random variables $X_1 , \ldots , X_n , Y_1 , \ldots , Y_n$ where $X_i$ have Gaussian probability distribution with mean $\mu_1$ and standard deviation $\sigma_1$, while $Y_i$ have Gaussian probability distribution with mean $\mu_2$ and standard deviation $\sigma_2$, let us consider the random variable $$ C := \frac{ \tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( (X_i - \tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j) (Y_i - \tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j) \right) }{ \sqrt{ \tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n ( X_i - \tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_j )^2 } \sqrt{ \tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n ( Y_i - \tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j )^2 } }.$$ Probably one should normalize $C$ by some coefficient depending on $n$ to make things look nicer. What is the probability distribution of $C$ (normalized appropriately)? Is there a reference? Probably it should be related to Student's $\mathbf{t}$-distribution.

Comment: The exact density for the bivariate normal case is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Using_the_exact_distribution

(When $\rho=0$, it is t-distributed, as you suggested.)

Comment: Note that the $\frac1n$s outside the brackets all cancel: some people would instead use $\frac1{n-1}$ to make these the "sample" covariances and variances but it does not change $C$

Comment: @user51547 Thanks. Do you recommend a book? The Wikipedia article cites a book by Rahman, but I can't find it online.

Comment: @Sasha Frequency Distribution of the Values of the Correlation Coefficient in Samples from an Indefinitely Large Population, R. A. Fisher (1915) https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring05/sta215/lec/Fish1915.pdf

Comment: @user51547 Thanks! Will take a look.